# CTRL+SPACE doesn't show the layout

Tags: android, android-studio

When I type `R.layout.` and press `CTRL+SPACE`, it shows me only `activity_main` layout, but I need `fragment_settings` layout that exist. And it doesn't see any of new layouts. How can I make this see this layout?

```
 package com.example.navdrawer;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

public class SettingsFragment extends Fragment {
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout./*fragment_settings*/, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Settings"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[My layouts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A45ns.png)
[what it offers me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CD8SL.png)

Comment: Because you have not imported `R.java` .. First write `R` then `CTRL+SPACE`  then import the proper R file then it will suggest all the resources .

Comment: please share fragment layout

Comment: Try to build the project and then try. Make sure there are no errors in layout files.

Comment: I i've jusnt tried to rebuild the project, it doesn't help

Comment: Try this sequence: 1) Build -> Make Project .. 2) Build -> Rebuild Project .. 3) File -> Invalidate caches / Restart

Comment: @Zain Yes it helped, thanks

Comment: great .. I will post as answer to help others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it's an android studio IDE bug, try to fix it by the following sequence:

1. Build -> Make Project
2. Build -> Rebuild Project
3. File -> Invalidate caches / Restart